# kineticjs canvas content disappears inside froala html editor

Tags: meteor, kineticjs, froala

I'm new in web development and this is also my first question here, so I hope I am precise enough.
What im trying to achieve is to have a text editor on a webpage, that of course can insert and edit text but also is able to insert blank guitar tablature, that can be edited by mouse- and keyboard events and save all the html content to a collection (Like create and save guitar notesheets).

The text thing is already working, I can save content to my collections or can show the collections content inside the editor, but I have some problems with the guitar tab inserts.

I'm using Meteor with the following packages:

```
brentjanderson:kinetic,
fortawesome:fontawesome,
froala:editor,
iron:router,
less,
meteor-platform,
nemo64:bootstrap,
peppelg:bootstrap-3-modal,
twbs:bootstrap
```

I want to use kineticjs for the guitar tab thing, because it is able to draw the blank tabs easily and access its content (for the editing I want to do).

For test purpose I just started to add a new kinetic stage with 2 layers (one for the guitar tab lines and one for the text) statically to an empty html page and it worked as it should. here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/dsrbhayd/

But if I want to use kinetic in conjunction with the froala editor's "insertHTML" function by inserting the kinetic div via custom button inside the editor I have the following issue: 
The div and canvas is inserted normally like on the html page above without the editor, but a few seconds later the content of both layers (var "text" and the horizontal lines, see fiddle) disappears. If I insert any text by typing something with the keyboard, right after I inserted the kinetic div, the content disappears immediately. 
If I switch to see the HTML code inside the froala editor (with the "show HTML" button in the toolbar) I am still able to see the inserted kinetic div and canvas elements, but it seems the content of the layers is "gone".
Here is another fiddle with the editor issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/un8sbrzd/

I worked on it for days but I cant get it. I tried to change some of the froala editors options (like I mentioned in the comments of the fiddle) but it didn't work.

Is it a kind of a refresh issue of the editor? Does anyone have some experience using kinetic inside a html editor?

It would be awesome if someone can help me.
Greetings

Comment: In your jsfiddle examples, Template is undefined.

Comment: Sorry there were some collection calls in the jsfiddle, I removed them.